How to use local cloudformation template file instead of uploading in s3?
I want to use multiple templates which will have multiple templates file directory and structure in cloudformation I don't want to use s3 bucket cause there will be multiple files later and I will use ci-cd pipeline to deploy my changes  this is my file i am trying to deploy in cloudformation
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: AWS EC2 Backup Policy for Production Environment

Resources:
  EC2LifecycleManagerStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: common/ec2/lifecyclemanager.yaml
      Parameters:
        RetentionPeriodDay: 5
        RetentionPeriodWeek: 2
        RetentionPeriodMonth: 2
        TargetResourceTags: FRONT
        PolicyDescription: Production Backup Policy
        RetentionTimeDay: '05:00'
        RetentionTimeWeek: '23:00'
        RetentionTimeMonth: '00:00'


this lifecycle manager policy contains some backup policy and schedules for the my ec2 instances so I want to utilize this prod.yaml file cause i will have multiple files and nested stacks. Is there any way to do this without s3? Here is what I tried using bash script
#!/bin/bash

TEMPLATE_FILE="root.yaml"
CAPABILITIES="CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
PROFILE="nit-iam"
STACK_NAME='PROD-INFRA'
CHANGE_SET_NAME='PROD-CHANGE'

#
AWS_PROFILE=$PROFILE aws cloudformation create-change-set \
  --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
  --change-set-name $CHANGE_SET_NAME \
  --template-body file://$TEMPLATE_FILE \
  --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM \
  --change-set-type CREATE

echo "Waiting for change set to be created..."
AWS_PROFILE=$PROFILE aws cloudformation wait change-set-create-complete \
  --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
  --change-set-name $CHANGE_SET_NAME

# Execute Change Set
echo "Executing change set..."
AWS_PROFILE=$PROFILE aws cloudformation execute-change-set \
  --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
  --change-set-name $CHANGE_SET_NAME


But this script is also failing saying template url must be supported url is there any way to do this?
